# Como remover eventos que são criados usando Arrow Functions?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Alguém sabe se existe em Javascript, uma forma de remover eventos que são criados usando Arrow Functions ao invés de criar uma função pra isso? Exemplo:

```
document.querySelector(element).addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
  console.log('evento');
})
```

Eu desejo remover esse evento criado, mas como posso fazê-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você nomear a *arrow function* e usar `.removeEventListener` onde o segundo argumento é o nome dado à função

Em vez de uma função anônima `(ev)=>`, coloque um nome, tipo `clique = (ev)=>`.

```js
let element = "#botao";
let clique; // declara a variável para o nome da função
document.querySelector(element).addEventListener('click', clique = (ev)=>{
  console.log("evento");
});

// esse listener abaixo é apenas para ilustrar o cancelamento do evento
document.querySelector("#cancelar").addEventListener('click', cancela = ()=>{
   // linhas de exemplo (apague)
   console.log("evento do botão cancelado");
   document.querySelector(element).textContent = "Clique-me e nada acontece :(";
   document.querySelector("#cancelar").textContent = "Evento foi cancelado";
   document.querySelector("#cancelar").removeEventListener('click', cancela);
   // fim das linhas de exemplo

   // remove o evento de clique no botão   
   document.querySelector(element).removeEventListener('click', clique);
});
```

```html
<button id="botao">Clique-me</button>
<button id="cancelar">Cancelar evento</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se o elemento possuir mais de um evento para o 'click' (neste caso), o interessante seria identificá-los, mas se for apenas 1-1, pode simplesmente remover todos os eventos associados ao elemento.

```
const events = getEventListeners(document.querySelector(element));
// check if exists a click event
events.click.forEach(ev => {
  document.querySelector(element).removeEventListener(ev.type, ev.listener)
});
```

Comment: Essa função `getEventListeners` não existe nos browsers, [apenas no console do Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities).

Comment: poxa, sabia não '-', é até bom saber que o console não reflete 100% um script em javascript